# How to listen for Modal submission on Slack Bolt?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've been looking through the docs for a day now, and still can't figure out this simple question: what is the @slack/bolt ^2.3.0 method that is used to listen for a Modal submission?

```
const slackbot = new App({ token, signingSecret });

slackbot.shortcut(
  "open_modal",
  async ({ ack, body, client, context, payload }) => {
    await ack();
    const result = await client.views.open({ ... });
  }
);

slackbot.METHOD_HERE(ID_HERE,
  async ({ ack }) => {
    ack();
    // handle modal submitted data here...
  }
);
```

What values take the place of `METHOD_HERE` and `ID_HERE` in the code above?
I am able to open a modal without problem via the global shortcuts menu; but can't seem to figure out how to capture user's submission of the modal.

For example, this never captures any submissions:

```
  slackbot.view("open_modal", async ({ ack }) => {
    ack();
    // do things here...
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `callback_id` used when you create the Modal view:

```
slackbot.shortcut(
  "open_modal",
  async ({ ack, body, client, context, payload }) => {
    await ack();

    const result = await client.views.open({
      trigger_id: body.trigger_id,

      view: {
        type: "modal",
        
        callback_id: "YOUR_CALLBACK_ID", // <= listen for this ID

        title: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Modal Title",
        },

        blocks: [ ... ],
      },
    });
  }
);
```

Then, to listen to submissions on the above Modal, use this:

```
app.view('YOUR_CALLBACK_ID', optionalMiddleWareFunction, async ({ payload }) => {
  const submittedValues = payload.view.state.values
  // do stuff with submittedValues
});
```

`callback_id` is the ID that you defined when creating modal view. You can see an example [here](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#composing_views).

You can read the corresponding official documentation [here](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#view_submissions).

Comment: Thanks, I've recommended an edit to the answer. I'll mark your response as the solution if you can improve the answer to be a bit more specific.